# Total number of count using aggrigate

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Without `$match` in the following code, I am getting the result but after include `$project` I am getting error "Someting went wrong" by mongodb.

```
[
    {
      $project: {
        mydata: {
          $cond: {
            if: { $isArray: '$activities' },
            then: {
              $size: '$activities'
            },

            else: 'NA'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    { $match: { mydata: { $gt: 1 } } }
  ];
```

So, I need to count of all `mydata` which value is greater than 1.

Answer (score 4):

Your `else` clause seems to be the one throwing an error since further down the pipeline you will be potentially comparing a string with a number. I would suggest giving the default a value `0` and check if that throws an error.

However, a better approach will be to to use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator as the [`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) query which allows you to query on computed fields:

```
db.collection.find({ 
    "$expr": {
        "$gt": [
            { "$size": { 
                "$cond": [ 
                    { "$isArray": "$activities" }, 
                    "$activities", 
                    []
                ]
            } },
            1
        ]
    }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

**@Chridam is correct.** Besides that, the following query can also do the trick:

```
db.collection.find({"activities.2":{$exists:true}}).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab919"),
    "activities" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab91a"), "activities" : [ 1, 2 ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab91b"), "activities" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab91c"), "activities" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab91d"), "activities" : [ 1 ] }
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d5fe03bc90be6af447ab919"),
    "activities" : [
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4
    ]
}
```

We are checking if the element on the 2nd index of the `activities` array is present or not. It's only possible if the activities size is greater than 1.